# Dual Boot unencrypted Windows 10 + encrypted Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, encryption, windows-10

I have Windows 10 installed on my laptop and I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 in encrypted form so I can boot into a non encrypted Windows 10 or an encrypted Ubuntu 14.04.

I have booted into the laptop using an Ubuntu 14.04 live cd and this is what the current partitions look like:

[image]

If I then start the Ubuntu 14.04 installation and select "something else" from the partition screen, I get this:

[image]

What do I need to do to the unused space in order to install Ubuntu 14.04 in encrypted form?

I have read many existing questions, but find them very confusing.

Comment: Do you just want to encrypt the home directories? If so, go ahead and install and check the option when it appears.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform a "full disk encryption" of your Ubuntu installation do the following:

- Boot live cd
- Open gparted
- Create 3 partitions:

  - boot (ext2) - If you have Windows installed with UEFI, this can be skipped,
  - root (ext4),
  - swap (linux-swap)
- Apply changes
- Open terminal and sudo -i
- Encrypt volumes root and swap

  ```
  cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher aes-xts-plain --key-size 512 --hash 
  sha512 --iter-time 2000 /dev/sdax
  ```
- Name the encrypted volumes

  ```
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 root
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 swap
  ```
- Make an ext4 filesystem inside and a swap space

  ```
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/root
  mkswap /dev/mapper/swap
  ```
- Proceed with OS installation
- Select Something else
- Set boot, root and swap partitions (Select each partition, press
  Change and set the appropriate values)
- Continue with installation. Press Install now.
- After installation is finished choose Continue testing
- Open terminal and sudo -i
- Chroot Magic

  ```
  cd /mnt
  mkdir root
  mount /dev/mapper/root root
  mount /dev/sda1 root/boot
  chroot root
  mount -t proc proc /proc
  mount -t sysfs sys /sys
  mount -o bind /dev root/dev
  ```
- Block Device & Filesystem Tables

  ```
  nano /etc/crypttab
  ```
- Open a second terminal

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```
- Enter the following content to the crypttab file

  ```
  root UUID= (find it from blkid) none luks
  swap UUID= (find it from blkid) none luks,swap
  ```
- Save and exit
- Open the file /etc/fstab and check that it has the root and swap
  entries
- Fix Hibernate and Update Init.
- Open with nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume and make the
  following change

  ```
  RESUME=/dev/mapper/swap
  ```
- Run in terminal the following command

  ```
  update-initramfs -u
  exit
  ```
- LUKS Header Backup. Open terminal and run the following commands

  ```
  cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda2 --header-backup-file /root/root.img
  cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda3 --header-backup-file /root/swap.img
  exit
  ```

The above guide was based on [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230192949/https://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I am puzzled. It seems to me that you are setting `sda2` and `sda3` to root and swap respectively, but surely that would overwrite the OP's Windows partitions? And even before then, you suggest creating a new partition table — surely that will delete all existing partitions, thereby destroying the existing Windows partitions, even the Windows recovery partition? Unless I am totally confused, your suggestion will destroy the OP's Windows setup, which is exactly the opposite of what was wanted.

Comment: The guide is meant to be generic so that it can be used in most of the cases with some alterations. You are correct, sda2 and sda3 should be replaced with the newly created partitions and of course no need to create a partition table, since one already exists.

Comment: -1 for broken Chroot magic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems here, install Ubuntu normally on the unused space (you can do some partition stuff like choosing different partitions for different folders etc. but if you don't want to do that, it's ok), during the installation progress, there will be an option called "encrypt my home folder" or something like that, check it, and you're pretty much done.

Even easier you can just make Windows take all the space, and check the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows", and it will show a very foolproof interface to you.

I may be wrong here and this is not what you're asking, tho.

Comment: encrypt home folder will only encrypt the home folder, what if you want to protect /tmp ? /lib ? /usr/lib ? ...